# How to increase a number inside a label according to a 'if' statement

Tags: vb.net

How do I increase a number inside a label according to a 'if' statement? Here is my code:

```
Dim uservalue As Integer
uservalue = TextBox1.Text

If tbxOperator.Text = "+" Then
    If uservalue = number + number1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Correct")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect")
    End If
End If

If tbxOperator.Text = "-" Then
    If uservalue = number - number1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Correct")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect")
    End If
End If

Dim rn As Random
rn = New Random
number = rn.Next(1, 9)
number1 = rn.Next(1, 9)
tbxOne.Text = number.ToString
tbxTwo.Text = number1.ToString

number2 = rn.Next(1, 3)
If number2 = 1 Then
    tbxOperator.Text = "+"
Else
    tbxOperator.Text = "-"
End If
```

I essentially have some functioning code that will generate a simple sum with a '+' or '-' operator and if the user types the correct answer a box appears saying 'correct'. What I would like to do is make it so when the user gets a correct answer, they are awarded a point in a label called 'Points'. Could somebody assist me in doing this?

Comment: use `IIF` something like `currpoints+ iif(win=true,winpoints,0-winpoints)`

Comment: `lblPoints.Text = currentPoints.ToString()` assuming there is a variable called `currentPoints`  pretty much the same thing you do with `number` and `currentPoints += 1` to increment it.  Be aware that VBA IsNot VB.NET

Comment: You should also start using Option Strict.  `uservalue = TextBox1.Text` with `uservalue` declared as an Integer, you cannot just assign a string to to it.

Comment: @Plutonix "lblPoints.Text = currentPoints.ToString() assuming there is a variable called currentPoints pretty much the same thing you do with number and currentPoints += 1 to increment it. Hi, thanks so much for the response I've implemented this into my code and it works however the points cap at 1, any work around for that?

Comment: The variable will have to have form/class level [Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) otherwise you are creating a new variable each time which will make it seem like it is "capped"

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `IIF` is deprecated and should not be used.  Use the proper `If` function instead.

Comment: Bradley Uffner apologies, this is a .NET question in a VBA forum, it was late :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your code (this is called "[refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)") so that you don't have to write the same thing more than once, for example the `MessageBox.Show("Correct")` lines.

Also, you can use [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) to replace some of the `If...Then` statements - it is only a slight improvement at the moment, but if you wanted to add, say multiplication and division then it makes it much simpler to do so.

**When the user gets an answer correct, you need to add one to (i.e. increment) their score and update the label.** Because we have refactored the code, this can be done in just one place instead of the two places which you would have had to do with the code as it was:

```
Option Infer On ' allow the compiler to figure out data types in Dim statements.
Option Strict On ' make sure all variable types match up.

Public Class Form1

    Dim rn As New Random
    Dim userPoints As Integer
    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer
    Dim testOperator As String

    Private Sub bnTestMe_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnTestMe.Click
        ' select two random numbers for the test
        number1 = rn.Next(1, 9)
        number2 = rn.Next(1, 9)

        tbxOne.Text = number1.ToString()
        tbxTwo.Text = number2.ToString()

        ' select a random operator for the test
        Dim operatorChoice = rn.Next(1, 3)

        Select Case operatorChoice
            Case 1
                testOperator = "+"
            Case 2
                testOperator = "-"
        End Select

        tbxOperator.Text = testOperator

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnCheckIt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnCheckIt.Click
        Dim uservalue As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim isCorrect As Boolean

        ' check if the user got it correct
        Select Case testOperator
            Case "+"
                isCorrect = (uservalue = number1 + number2)
            Case "-"
                isCorrect = (uservalue = number1 - number2)
        End Select

        ' perform appropriate actions depending on if the user was correct.
        If isCorrect Then
            userPoints += 1
            MessageBox.Show("Correct")
            lblPoints.Text = userPoints.ToString()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect")
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

I used slightly different variable names than you showed so that they are more consistent. I used a button named "bnTestMe" to present the test to the user, and a button named "bnCheckIt" to check the answer.

`userPoints += 1` is short for `userPoints = userPoints + 1`. (There are some technical points about `+=` when it isn't used on simple local variables: [Compound Assignment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one/) - which you probably don't need to know about yet.)

I stored the numbers and the operator for the test in variables so that there is no chance of the user cheating by typing in other values.

The line `isCorrect = (uservalue = number1 + number2)` works like this: `(uservalue = number1 + number2)` gives a [Boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx) (i.e. True or False) result, like when you use `If (uservalue = number1 + number2) Then...`. That result is assigned to the `isCorrect` variable. Then we can use `isCorrect` later to see if the user got it right.